# Shape of pytorch model.parameter is inconsistent with how it's defined in the model

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I'm attempting to extract the weights and biases from a simple network built in PyTorch. My entire network is composed of nn.Linear layers. When I create a layer by calling `nn.Linear(in_dim, out_dim)`, I expect the parameters that I get from calling `model.parameters()` for that model to be of shape `(in_dim, out_dim)` for the weight and `(out_dim)` for the bias. However, the weights that come out of `model.parameters()` are instead of shape `(out_dim, in_dim)`.

The intention of my code is to be able to use matrix multiplication to perform a forward pass using only numpy, not any PyTorch. Because of the shape inconsistency, matrix multiplications throw an error. How can I fix this?

Here is my exact code:

```
class RNN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, dim_input, dim_recurrent, dim_output):

        super(RNN, self).__init__()

        self.dim_input = dim_input
        self.dim_recurrent = dim_recurrent
        self.dim_output = dim_output

        self.dense1 = nn.Linear(self.dim_input, self.dim_recurrent)
        self.dense2 = nn.Linear(self.dim_recurrent, self.dim_recurrent, bias = False)
        self.dense3 = nn.Linear(self.dim_input, self.dim_recurrent)
        self.dense4 = nn.Linear(self.dim_recurrent, self.dim_recurrent, bias = False)
        self.dense5 = nn.Linear(self.dim_recurrent, self.dim_output)

#There is a defined forward pass

model = RNN(12, 100, 6)

for i in model.parameters():
    print(i.shape())
```

The output is:

```
torch.Size([100, 12])
torch.Size([100])
torch.Size([100, 100])
torch.Size([100, 12])
torch.Size([100])
torch.Size([100, 100])
torch.Size([6, 100])
torch.Size([6])
```

The output should, if I'm correct, be:

```
torch.Size([12, 100])
torch.Size([100])
torch.Size([100, 100])
torch.Size([12, 100])
torch.Size([100])
torch.Size([100, 100])
torch.Size([100, 6])
torch.Size([6])
```

What is my issue?

Comment: Please share the relevant code and highlight the exact issue there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see there is not the (out_dim, in_dim), it is just the shape of the weight matrix. When you call `print(model)` you can see that input and output features are correct:

```
RNN(
  (dense1): Linear(in_features=12, out_features=100, bias=True)
  (dense2): Linear(in_features=100, out_features=100, bias=False)
  (dense3): Linear(in_features=12, out_features=100, bias=True)
  (dense4): Linear(in_features=100, out_features=100, bias=False)
  (dense5): Linear(in_features=100, out_features=6, bias=True)
)
```

You can check the source code to see that the **weights** are actually **transposed** before calling `matmul`.

*`nn.Linear` is define here:

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/linear.html#Linear*

You can check the `forward`, it looks like this:

```
def forward(self, input):
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
```

*`F.linear` is define here:

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/functional.html*

The respective line for multiplying the weights is:

```
output = input.matmul(weight.t())
```

As mentioned above you can see that the **weights** are **transposed** before applying `matmul` and therefore the shape of the weights is different than you expected.

So if you want to do the matrix multiplication manually, you do:

```
# dummy input of length 5
input = torch.rand(5, 12)
# apply layer dense1 (without bias, for bias just add + model.dense1.bias)
output_first_layer = input.matmul(model.dense1.weight.t())
print(output_first_layer.shape)
```

Just as you would expect from your `dense1` it returns:

```
torch.Size([5, 100])
```

I hope this explains your observations with the shape :)

Comment: Is there a reason that the weights are transposed?

Comment: @SamuelCarpenter actually I don't know :) I asked a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465608/pytorch-shape-of-nn-linear-weights

Comment: @SamuelCarpenter found the answer for this, you can check it out on the link I posted.