# Why are the dimension of the weight in torch.nn.functional.linear (out,in) instead of (in,out)

Tags: machine-learning, matrix, deep-learning, pytorch

In the documentation of torch.nn.functional.linear (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.linear.html), the dimensions of the weight input are (out_features, in_features) then the wight matrix is transposed when computing the output: y=xA^T+b. Why are they doing this instead of taking a matrix W of dimensions (in_features, out_features) and doing y=xW+b?

By doing y=xW+b the dimensions will match and so I cannot find a clear reason for the above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyTorch - shape of nn.Linear weights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465608/pytorch-shape-of-nn-linear-weights)

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear why they do this. It was implemented that way for some reason a long time ago and now it's backward incompatible to change it. You can find discussion of this [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/2159). The transpose operation doesn't add any overhead so there's no performance incentive to change it.